# Script in ASP to VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Given this line of a `Javascript` function in `ASP` :

```
App.Hidden1.setValue(
  Ext.encode(App.GridPanel1.getRowsValues({ selectedOnly: false }))
)
```

I have no idea how to convert that to VB. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.encode` is a function in the Ext JS library (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext-method-encode) that encodes a value into a JSON string. To replace this you can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) in `System.Web.Script.Serialization`, which can be used like so:

```
Dim serializer as New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim arrayJson as String = serializer.Serialize(myArray)
```

Comment: ah ok , thats seems a good method , but what about "App.GridPanel1.getRowsValues({ selectedOnly: false })" how to put it in the code since it is still javascipt ?

Comment: Well I would say that's also something else built into Ext JS but I can't find anything in their documentation. Is there anything in your codebase that extends Ext JS? I'm just guessing but it looks like it's returning some kind of JSON array from the rows and columns in the grid.